# having formatting error in c#

Tags: c#, number-formatting

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OpenFiles(); PrintReportHeadings();
    while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        ParseLineIn();

        PrintDetailLine();
        Computing();
        sides++;
    }


    CloseFiles();

}

static void PrintDetailLine()
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,2}  {1}", sides, polyName);        
}

static void Computing()
{
    for (n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
    {
        p = (Math.Pow(n, 2) * (sides - 2) - n * (sides - 4)) / 2;
        Console.Write("{0}", p);
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm working with. I have my report headings where they need to be and when reading in polygon names from file, they go into the right spot with the amount of sides. But when trying to compute the nth amount of dots in polygonal number, it pushes the amount of sides of polygon and name of polygon to the right side. not sure what I'm doing wrong. been staring at this for 4 hours now.

Comment: i thought if you have {0,2} it holds 2 places. it doesn't give me a compiler error or anything

Comment: can you give a list `string[]` of lines you read in to reproduce?

Comment: `Triangular
Square
Pentagonal
Hexagonal
Heptagonal
Octagonal
Nonagonal
Decagonal
Hendecagonal
Dodecagonal
Tridecagonal
Tetradecagonal
Pentadecagonal
Hexadecagonal
Heptadecagonal
Octadecagonal
Nonadecagonal
Icosagonal
Icosihenagonal
Icosidigonal
Icositrigonal
Icositetragonal`

is all it reads in. just 24 polygons

Comment: Tiangle has 5 sides :-O? I am assuming each one is side length?

Comment: in the table, its categorized by the amount of sides. goes from 3-24. then lists shape, then the nth amount of dots it takes when so many dots make up one side

Comment: What the format of the file you read, and what/where the error exception. Computing method do nothing with polygon Name except it handle the increment variable sides.

Comment: the format is it reads the 24 names, each on a new line

Comment: In computing method u use constant number n <=9 with all shapes, but ,e.g. , square is 4 sides. u should control n.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

Output:

```
 3       Triangular   1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45
 4           Square   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81
 5       Pentagonal   1   5  12  22  35  51  70  92 117
 6        Hexagonal   1   6  15  28  45  66  91 120 153
 7       Heptagonal   1   7  18  34  55  81 112 148 189
 8        Octagonal   1   8  21  40  65  96 133 176 225
 9        Nonagonal   1   9  24  46  75 111 154 204 261
10        Decagonal   1  10  27  52  85 126 175 232 297
11     Hendecagonal   1  11  30  58  95 141 196 260 333
12      Dodecagonal   1  12  33  64 105 156 217 288 369
13     Tridecagonal   1  13  36  70 115 171 238 316 405
14   Tetradecagonal   1  14  39  76 125 186 259 344 441
15   Pentadecagonal   1  15  42  82 135 201 280 372 477
16    Hexadecagonal   1  16  45  88 145 216 301 400 513
17   Heptadecagonal   1  17  48  94 155 231 322 428 549
18    Octadecagonal   1  18  51 100 165 246 343 456 585
19    Nonadecagonal   1  19  54 106 175 261 364 484 621
20       Icosagonal   1  20  57 112 185 276 385 512 657
21   Icosihenagonal   1  21  60 118 195 291 406 540 693
22     Icosidigonal   1  22  63 124 205 306 427 568 729
23    Icositrigonal   1  23  66 130 215 321 448 596 765
24  Icositetragonal   1  24  69 136 225 336 469 624 801
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Source Code:

```
class Program
{
    static int sides = 3;
    private static int maxPolyNameLength;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "Triangular Square Pentagonal Hexagonal Heptagonal Octagonal Nonagonal Decagonal Hendecagonal Dodecagonal Tridecagonal Tetradecagonal Pentadecagonal Hexadecagonal Heptadecagonal Octadecagonal Nonadecagonal Icosagonal Icosihenagonal Icosidigonal Icositrigonal Icositetragonal"
            .Split(' ');

        maxPolyNameLength = input.Max(x => x.Length);


        foreach (var s in input)
        {
            PrintDetailLine(s);
            Computing();
            Console.WriteLine();
            sides++;

        }

    }

    static void PrintDetailLine(string polyName)
    {
        Console.Write($"{{0,2}}  {{1,{maxPolyNameLength}}} ", sides, polyName);
    }

    static void Computing()
    {
        double p = 0;


        for (var n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
        {
            p = (Math.Pow(n, 2) * (sides - 2) - n * (sides - 4)) / 2;
            Console.Write("{0,3} ", p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! exactly, but i need the numbers formatted to fit the table. i will post a picture example in just one sec.

Comment: im not sure what var is just yet, haven't made it that far. i still have to calculate the sum of reciprocals and place it in the last column

Comment: var is just a lazy way of pecifying a type (its type is inferred from the variable assigned to it). In the case of `var input` it is the same as `string[] input` as `"xxxxx".Split()`  returns a `string[]` (Array of Strings)

Comment: okay, the only problem is i'm supposed to use streamreader to read the polygon names from a file and not input the names directly in the code myself

Comment: then thats fine, change the `foreach (var s in input)` to your `while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)`

Comment: Do you get anything else in your file? Or just a straight list of poly names? How do you know how many sides the first poly has?

Comment: straight list of poly names. if you look at the link i posted, those are my instructions. just the poly names and 3-24. when i posted you code, for some reason the triangle's math is always incorrect and its in the negative.. hmmm